# replaceState before back/forward button click

Tags: javascript, html

I need to call `replaceState` before the user leaves the current page (e.g. back/forward button click) so the history has the most current state the next time the page is loaded on `popstate`. How to?

---

I guess the alternative would be to call `replaceState` everytime the state changes, but that sounds kinda messy to me.

---

Found a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10703979/39923). A "pre" popstate event would be ideal for this.

Comment: With as much rep as you have, you should know the first question many people will ask: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @Chad I haven't tried anything, looking for the correct approach. To me theory is more important than something that just works. I might be missing something or looking the problem from the wrong angle.